# How to find $u$ for $u$ substitution in $\frac{1}{x^2+4}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, substitution

In the problem $$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{x^2+4}$$
why is the $u$ for $u$ substitution equal to $\cfrac{x}{2}$?

Comment: It is because you would like to get a function which is a multiple of $\frac{1}{u^2+1}$, which is well known to be an arctan substitution. You could just as well do it in one step, which would be: $tan(u) = x/2$.

Answer (score 1):

The substitution may be helpful for beginners to convert the derivative to a more recognisable format for some as this substitution eliminates the constant term from the expression in the denominator.

After the substitution you will end up with the derivative of-

$$\frac{1}{8}\frac{1}{u^2+1}$$

Which is directly written as an example in many textbooks. Then you can undo the substitution to get the answer.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks a lot. I'll learn it in a while